# Get initial requested url in spring security 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Recently I have upgrade my all project API's like Spring, Spring Security, Hibernate, Maven, Java. Before upgrade I was using Spring 3 and Spring Security 2.
Now I am using Spring 4 and Spring Security 4 in my project and I have also used cas authentication for login.
When user logged in my application, based on the initial requested URL I want to set target URL of user. Before upgrade it was working fine.

I was using this `SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY` to get initial request URL.

Now I am using -

```
savedRequest = new HttpSessionRequestCache().getRequest(request, response);
```

to get initial request but it always return `null`.

Is there any way to get initial request of user after login?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I used the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

In my case I had an authorization server at `localhost:8081` and the secured UI at `localhost:8083/app`.

In the Authorization server I created the following class:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {   

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        setDefaultTargetUrl("http://localhost:8083/app");
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

In my case there were 3 scenarios of user logging in:

1. User navigates to `http://localhost:8081/login`
2. User navigates to `http://localhost:8083/app`
3. User navigates to any secured url within the app like `http://localhost:8083/app/files`

The class above covers every one of these scenarios by redirecting the user to the original url or if the user choose to login via `http://localhost:8081/login`, it redirects them to the default target url which is `http://localhost:8083/app`.